# Inverting array elements (bitwise) doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

I've tried to invert an array element today and it didn't work. Is there a reason that e.g.

```
uint8_t array[2] = {0xFF,0x0A};
...
if( 0xF5 == ~(array[1]){
   // never got here
}
```

Doesn't work? Compiler didn't show any errors.

Comment: Integer promotion strikes again

Comment: @canbus  Show minimal compiled example that demonstrates the problem. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @harold I did not see the operator ~.:)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(0xF5 == ~(array[1]))
```

This happens because `array[1]` is promoted to `int` before inversion is applied to it. Hence when you apply inversion on promoted value of `array[1]` you get: 0xFFFFFFF5, which is not equal to 0x000000F5

As noted you can cast the expression on the right hand side of the equality operator to `uint8_t` if you want to do comparison.

Comment: Yes `array[1]` will be promoted to `int`. Assuming `int` is 32-bit, 2's complement, ~(array[1]) will be `-11`, or `0xFFFFFFF5`.

Comment: What does it mean exactly? Could you explain?

Comment: @canbus C can't do arithmetic on types smaller than `int`. Anything smaller is implicitly promoted to `int' prior to operation.

Comment: @FUZxxl Oh, I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

C promotes integer types to `int` (or larger) when performing integer arithmetic.  To get the value you desire, you can cast the result of the bitwise complement back down to `uint8_t` before comparing, as follows:

```
if (0xF5 == (uint8_t) ~array[1]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`~(array[1])` evalutes to `~(0x0A)`. On a platform where an `int` is a 32-bit number, due to integer promotion, that is equivalent to `~(0x0000000A)`, which is the same as `0xFFFFFFF5`.

Hence, `0xF5 == ~(array[1])` translates to `0xF5 == 0xFFFFFFF5`, which obviously evaluates to false.

In order to make your comparison work, you can use another bitwise operator.

```
if( 0xF5 == (~(array[1]) & 0xFF) )
```

This makes sure that everything but the last bit of the promoted integer on the RHS of the `==` operator is zeroed out.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if (0xF5 == (uint8_t)~(array[1])){
```

or:

```
if (0xF5 == (~(array[1]) & 0xFF)){
```